# Select Distinct Colum of 3 inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, distinct

I want to Select distinct RoomName in this sql statement, I don't know to put distinct where in this sql statement.

```
SELECT Distinct
R.RoomID,R.RoomName,RT.RTypeName,RT.RTypePrice,RB.RBedName,RB.RBedPrice,
G.GalName,G.GalPath

FROM tbRoom as R
   INNER JOIN tbRoomType as RT ON R.RTypeID = RT.RTypeID
   INNER JOIN tbRoomBed as RB ON R.RBedID = RB.RBedID
   INNER JOIN tbGallery as G ON R.GalID = G.GalID
WHERE R.RoomID NOT IN(
    SELECT RD.RoomID FROM tbReservationDetail as RD WHERE
    RD.ArrivalDate <= '$dep' AND RD.DepartureDate >= '$arr' AND R.RoomID =
    RD.RoomID
)
```

Comment: Did you checked with `DISTINCT` and without `DISTINCT`, what was the result ?

Comment: What do you mean with distinct? You only want each roomname to appear once? If yes, what other data do you want to appear in your select?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT R.RoomName FROM ... !?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT R.RoomID,R.RoomName,RT.RTypeName,RT.RTypePrice,RB.RBedName,RB.RBedPrice, G.GalName,G.GalPath
FROM tbRoom AS R
INNER JOIN tbRoomType AS RT ON R.RTypeID = RT.RTypeID
INNER JOIN tbRoomBed AS RB ON R.RBedID = RB.RBedID
INNER JOIN tbGallery AS G ON R.GalID = G.GalID
WHERE R.RoomID NOT IN(
    SELECT RD.RoomID 
    FROM tbReservationDetail AS RD 
    WHERE RD.ArrivalDate <= '$dep' AND RD.DepartureDate >= '$arr' AND R.RoomID = RD.RoomID
)
GROUP BY R.RoomName;
```